# Fetch field from a json object using Liquid and variables

Tags: liquid

I'm trying to create a push notification using a Liquid template but don't know how to extract a specific field from the json.

I have a json which I create an Liquid object
`{% assign object = response | replace: '=>', ':' | json_parse %}`

The json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "en": "Hello!:",
        "sv": "Hej!"
    }
]
```

I can access the field using: `{{object[0].en}}` which will give me "Hello"

However, I have the language stored in a variable called `language` and I don't want to hardcode the language.

Instead, I would like to use the variable `language` to fetch the correct value but I can not get it to work. I have tried the below:

```
  {{object[0]['${language}']}}
  {{object[0][${language}]}}
  {{object[0].${language}}}
  {{object[0].'${language}'}}
```

Any ideas how I can fetch the correct value based in the json object using my `language` variable?

---

**edit**: I figure out that I needed to add a blankspace after an before the double curly brackets, then it works perfect e.g
`{{ object[2][${most_recent_locale}] }}`